# Beautifulsoup how to fetch particular tr and td data and also writing in csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

Structure of HTML file is below:
[image: Structure of HTML File]

---

I want to fetch the TR data which is showing in bottom, every tr has 7 td tag and tr and td doesnt have the class or id, how to fetch that data.

```
table = soup.find('td', attrs={'class': 'strip'})

result = table.text
print result
```

It prints all the result as vertically, This is the single td data.

```
           12345
           Name
           Address
           2
           Systems
           Machines
           Pawar,Vikas
           04/14/15 12:56 PM
           Pawar , Vikas
```

I want to display it horizontally like:

> 1234,Name,Address,2,Systems,Machines,Pawar Vikas etc..

and also i want to write that data to csv file.
Can anyone please help me, as am new to beautifulsoup.

Comment: why have you tagged it beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 1):

You can print it in one line by adding a `,` with the print statement. like

```
print result,
```

Writing this result in a csv is not very difficult. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

In short, append the results in a list and use the list to write csv file.

```
results = []
results.append(result)

with open('results.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(results)
```